# RxJS Observable filtering and grouping

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm new to reactive programming and it's a bit complicated sometimes.

Given a list from a service event[]

Event looks like

```
Event:
{
 beginDate: Date,
 name: string,
 type: State
}

State:
{
  PENDING, FINISHED, UPCOMING
}
```

I want to group this in following structure

```
GroupedByMonthEvent:
{
monthYear: Date,
event: Event
}
```

In imperative style I write it:

```
allEvents$: Observable<Tournament[]>;
allEventsGrouped$: Observable<GroupedByMonthEvent[]>;  

...
this.allEvents$ = this.store.select(state => state.events);

this.allEventsGrouped$ = this.allEvents$.map(t => {
      return _.chain(t).sortBy(function (value) {
        return new Date(value.beginDate);
      })
        .groupBy(function (event) {
          return moment(event.beginDate).format('MMMM YYYY');
        }).toPairs()
        .map(function (events: Event[]) {
          return _.zipObject(['monthYear', 'events'], events);
        })
        .value();
    });
```

Next I want to filter that Observerable.
I tried to .map and .filter that collection, but I don't get it.
Now I just subscribe to the Observerable and filter it old fashioned.

Can someone help with RxJS magic to group and filter it in one simple statement?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Observables.

You can combine multiple Observables into one using ForkJoin:

See this link here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

snippet:

```
/*
  when all observables complete, give the last
  emitted value from each as an array
*/
const example = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
  //emit 'Hello' immediately
  Rx.Observable.of('Hello'),
  //emit 'World' after 1 second
  Rx.Observable.of('World').delay(1000),
  //emit 0 after 1 second
  Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(1),
  //emit 0...1 in 1 second interval
  Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(2),
  //promise that resolves to 'Promise Resolved' after 5 seconds
  myPromise('RESULT')
);
//output: ["Hello", "World", 0, 1, "Promise Resolved: RESULT"]
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```